# Display matched column of a record highlighted in a webpage

Tags: html, postgresql, cgi

I'am trying to create a web based telephone directory search using CGI and postgres database.My select query is:

```
(select * from tel_dir 
 where
   name ~* '$var1' or 
   city ~* '$var1' or
   state ~* '$var1' or
   telno ~* '$var1')
INTERSECT
(select * from tel_dir
 where
   name ~* '$var2' or
   city ~* '$var2' or
   state ~* '$var2' or
   telno ~* '$var2');
```

Along with the result set obtained after executing the above query,how to get the first column name against which $var1 or $var2 matches in each row obtained.so that I can show that column value highlighted in the web page.

Comment: Can you provide a small sample data set, and desired result set ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not too clear from your question but assuming you can compare the two values (I'll do this as php)

```
<?php 
if ($var1 == $var2)
     {
      $cssClass = 'foobar';
     }
?>
```

for your css...

```
.foobar{
   background-color: #cccccc; /* or any colour you like */
}
```

in your web page where the results are display... (you will need to reference the php or similar as the first code example in the top of the page where you are displaying the results for this to work)

```
<div class="<?php echo $cssClass; ?>" >
     <p>matched results output</p>
</div>
```